# Transfer files from recovery on a Nexus 10

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, rom, file-transfer, samsung-nexus-10

My Nexus 10 won't boot, so I need to copy a ROM from my computer to the device. Since it won't boot, I need to copy it via recovery. I can flash recoveries as needed and install software on my computer as needed, but I need to get the ROM on there!

Comment: What are you actually asking? I don't understand the question.

Comment: It turns out I just forgot to forward the device to my virtual machine. Derp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ADB on a computer while your device is in recovery. To copy a file from the computer via usb, use this:

```
adb push /path/to/local/ROM.zip /sdcard/
```

This will copy the local file to the device in the specified location.  Directories can be created on the device via the shell:

```
adb shell
```

and using the usual shell commands to navigate around and create directories. This [beginners guide](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-adb-quick-guide/) may also help you.

You might also consider getting a [USB OTG adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00871Q5PI). This way you'd be able to put the files you need on a USB drive, plug it into your N10, and flash the files you need. I do it this way on my N7 with TWRP all the time so that I can erase everything on it without worrying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Wugfresh's [Nexus Root Toolkit](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&output=search&q=Nexus%20Root%20Toolkit&sout=1)? It should be able to do that.